# 404 not found on phpmyadmin - nginx docker

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, phpmyadmin

I want to run phpmyadmin and my API on same domain using docker and nginx, as:

api => `localhost:8888/`
phpmyadmin => `localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/`

Docker config for phpmyadmin service:

```
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin
  restart: always
  environment:
    PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    PMA_HOST: mysql
    PMA_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
    PMA_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
  depends_on:
    - mysql
```

This is nginx service config:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:stable-alpine
  volumes:
    - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
  depends_on:
    - api
    - phpmyadmin
  restart: always
  ports:
    - '8888:80'
```

And this is nginx config file:

```
upstream pma {
  server phpmyadmin;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  # resolver 127.0.0.1;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://api:8889/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location ~/phpmyadmin(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://pma/$1/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, I can use the API, as `localhost:8888/url` and it works fine. But when I request `localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/`, it loads it, but js and all css gives 404 not found, here's the console preview:

[image]

I have been scratching my head from more than 3 hours to fix this, tried my best, but it doesn't work. I am pretty much new to nginx so can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI` in the docker phpmyadmin service environments? Checkout [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/):

> `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI` - the full URL to phpMyAdmin. Sometimes needed when used in a reverse-proxy configuration.

Add it like:

```
PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI: localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/
```

Please notice the last `/` that is very very important, if you miss it, it will not work.